# how to get Campaign name from campaign ID using facebook SDK?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

I have created a campaign using below code.

```
fields = []    
params = { 
'name': 'My campaign',
'objective': 'LINK_CLICKS',  
'status': 'PAUSED',
}

AdAccount(id).create_campaign(
  fields=fields,
  params=params,
)
```

when I try to get campaigns by using below code,

```
my_account = AdAccount('act_xxxxxxxxx')
campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns()
```

I'm getting only campaign ID's.

How to know the name of the campaign ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future reference to others.

I found the answer. We can check that by adding extra columns in ad manager dashboard. At the right corner there was `Plus symbol(+)` which is `automatic column suggestions are on`. Click the `customize columns --> In standard events --> settings --> Object names and ID's`.

Answer (score 1):

```
campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns(fields=[
    Campaign.Field.name,
    Campaign.Field.configured_status,
])
print (campaigns)
```

Comment: Although this may be a right answer, there is a lack of explanation. Please improve your answer to explain it.